# Is it possible to use more than one ad SDK in an Android app?

Tags: android, admob

Recently updated my app and I want to know if I can use AdMob when I already have another ad SDK.

I'm currently using AdMob and Appodeal to monetize my App.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you want to know if it is possible to use the admob SDK together with another ad SDK or do you want to know if it is possible to use the admob network inside another ad platform?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I want to use Admobi sdk together with another Ad SDK

Comment: Not sure how you would alternate between the calls used by each of the SDKs about the only way to find out is to try it. Make sure you use the google  test codes before you try and go live.

Comment: I already did and it worked that, does google this in their policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you can add more than one Ad SDK in project.
Only thing you need to understand that how you are going to call/use that Ad SDK. Suppose you already have Ad SDK X and now you want to Add AdMob. Options:

1. AdMob can be the primary Ad Source and X can be added as mediated Ad Source (If supported by AdMob)
2. X can be the primary Ad Source and AdMob can be added as mediated Ad Source( If supported by X)
3. If No SDK is primary Ad Source or (X and AdMob) are not in mediated Ad sources to each other then you need to manually write code to call Ads from these Ad Sources depending on Ad Load callbacks.
   Hopefully, this will help to understand , how these works!

Comment: Thanks a lot friend this helped a lot, I've done practically everything and I'm using independent sdks each with its api or code. My question was but if this is not prohibited according to admobi policies.

Comment: I am not sure but i think it is OK to use AdMob with other Ad SDK. Anyways, once you upload the app to playstore and if it is violation of AdMob policy, you will get mail and you can revert back and re-upload. And if you want to use SDK X along with AdMob, you can use X as a mediated Ad Source of AdMob..that i am very sure AdMob will allow.